# Why does visual studio hang in debug mode with script-debugging enabled?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, google-chrome

When I run my Visual Studio 2022 solution (mvc asp.net core 6) in **debug mode with no break points** then iisexpress.exe starts the application at localhost and **works properly**.

When I set a **single breakpoint** anywhere in **any controller action** not related to the startup process and run the solution in **debug mode** then iisexpress.exe starts the application at localhost but the **process never reaches the index page and seems to stall**.
The Step Over Icon (F10) in the Visual Studio menu never gets activated.

**Edit**: I found out that I unintentionally enabled script-debugging. After disabling it the debugger worked again.

Now I wonder why does the debugger freeze when script-debugging is enabled and what settings/conditions must be met that the debugger works with script-debugging.

Explanations for the workings of script-debugging will be appreciated gratefully.

Comment: Is a javascript debugger bug, I am having the same issue

Comment: I'm having the same issue and can't figure out why. I reinstalled VS 2022 and still have the issue. Tried both Chrome and Edge and still no luck.

Comment: Yup, same here.  Removing all the breakpoints seems to make it load with script debugging on.

Comment: Same problem. It just started occuring a day or two ago.

The problem only seems to occur when I use Chrome or (I think) Edge. On Firefox it works fine. My guess is that the problem resides in the debug-connection between VS, IISExpress and Chrome/ chromium.

Try and see if you get the same results as me when you do this:
* Start your debug session with Crome, as usual
* Observe how it hangs on startup
* Take the URL in the stalled browser window, and paste it into a freshly opened Chrome browser
* In my case, everything seems to work well in the newly opened browser window

Comment: Can confirm that Firefox works correctly with VS script debugging.

Comment: I think I had Script debugging enabled before I had this problem - I could debug in either Chrome or in Visual Studio. I would only work in Visual Studio after I had did F12 to debug in Chrome with a Break Point in Chrome. I just tried it: Nope. Disabling Script debugging in Visual Studio does not fix that problem for me.

Comment: @TorbjörnJosefsson I was able to recreate your findings with starting the debugger using Edge. It stalled due to script debugging being enabled, opened a fresh browser instance, navigated to my localhost, and boom, it worked. I think I'll be using FF for now until this is corrected.

Comment: Issue was tracked on VS Dev Community here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Launching-Chrome-Debugger-fails-if-break/10305614
Received an update to Edge this morning and it seems to be working again. Chrome is still broken.